# What is the best way to sign in a user using Auth0 for a Google Chrome Extension (Manifest v3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auth0, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

In Google Chrome manifest v2, the background script had persistent store which allowed the Auth0.js to store the auth token in memory. To augment this, the developer could store the authentication token in local storage. Storing the auth token alone is not a good solution because this would require the app to fetch the token from storage every time it needs to run an authenticated query. Which is where having the auth token in memory comes in handy.

Unfortunately, this goes away with manifest v3 as service workers are not guaranteed to be persistent. I've seen solutions out there suggesting that you could use the options page to initiate Auth0 login but it is not clear to me if the options page is persistent either and whether or not it shares a persistent store with the other components of the extension (i.e. foreground, background, popup).

So my question boils down to this, what is the best practice for logging a user in (using Auth0) and keeping the user logged in between browser sessions?

Answer (score 0):

First off, a bit of a frame challenge: why is having the token in storage while the background is unloaded a problem? If the requests are frequent enough for storage access to be a significant slowdown, on those timescales the background won't be unloaded (only if it's been idle for some period). Do you really have a case where you have requests that are infrequent BUT cannot tolerate storage access latency?

---

That said, there is a new tool for storing small amounts of data persistently throughout one browser session (= lifetime of memory of prevously-persistent background) but between Service Worker loads: [`chrome.storage.session` storage area](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-session).

If you look at the [rationale document for this API](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N34xDVIeIM2A6egjoKUQqjqcuQ2s2W8_v_H8ciFWBu4/edit), it mentions specifically:

> ## Use Cases
>
> ### Computationally-intensive data
>
> Data that is too computationally-intensive to compute every time the Service  Worker starts up
>
> ### Unencrypted sensitive data
>
> Unencrypted sensitive data that needs to be accessed for the duration of the browser session.

Check on the sensitive data, maybe-check (my challenge applies) on the "avoid computing every time". Note that the API is still the same as the regular storage: so, still asynchronous - if that's a problem.